# Can I use the 'scroll:1' option when using 'setFrozenColumns' in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I need to display data without paging using the 'scroll:1' option and with fixed columns in the grid I am creating.
Therefore, I used the 'setFrozenColumns' function, but it did not work properly due to the scroll option, and I found out through the official documentation that this feature cannot be used.
So I modified the 'setFrozenColumns' method in the 'jqgrid.min.js' file like this:

```
if($t.p.subGrid === true || $t.p.treeGrid === true || $t.p.cellEdit === true || $t.p.sortable /*|| $t.p.scroll*/ )
    {
        return;
    }
```

I commented out '|| $t.p.scroll'.
It seems to be working well after this modification.

Is it safe to use the function this way?
 My version is 5.0.1.